# FFT on audio file in android

Tags: java, android, audio, fft

I have been searching for Fast Fourier Transform on a audio file but i couldn't get a proper one reg this.All i want to do is to input a audio file and do a FFT on it and give back the result.If there are any links which could serve my purpose will be much helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.fftw.org/ is a C library for FFT.  You'd have to use the NDK to hook into it.

There are a gpl version for open source projects and a pay version for proprietary projects.

Comment: Thanks levis501.I went through the doc of fft.My doubt is that how to convert a audio file into a complex array of numbers which is given as input to the FFT.

Comment: I suggest starting a new question to address converting an audio file to binary data.

Answer (score 0):

I know some folks have used kissfft on Android. It is smaller than fftw and is bsd licensed (commercial friendly)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple task, you can use either jTransform or Badlogic's libgdx.fft.
Libgdx.fft is based off the KissFFT native libraries Mark Borgerding mentioned.

Have a look at this blog which shows the basic use of [fft with libgdx in Android](http://www.digiphd.com/android-java-simple-fft-libgdx/) with a real valued float array.